# How to stop camera animation once it reaches a certain position on click using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a small piece of code that animates the camera to zoom in on an earth model on click. How to stop camera animation once it reaches a certain position.

When you click on the sphere model the render function is called that starts the camera animation loop. the camera position starts at 20 and goes on reducing. how can I stop the animation once camera position reaches 5.

https://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/ve9qb2cx/10/

```
var domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);

domEvents.addEventListener(earth, 'click', function(event){
    console.log('you clicked on the earth');

    alert("test");


var render = function (actions) {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        console.log(camera.position.z); // starts at 20 and reduces with every call

        camera.position.z -= 0.1;

        requestAnimationFrame( render );

    };

    render();

    // cameraloop();


}, false)
```

Right now the camera continues to animate without stopping. I would like to stop the camera once it reaches position 5.

Comment: Check `if(camera.position.z >= 5) camera.position.z -= 0.1;`

Comment: Use tween.js or GSAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set controls.minDistance to 4.11 (sphere radius + camera near plane distance + a little fudge) (or whatever you want the min distance to be)

https://jsfiddle.net/2nbgfkpy/

And then after you move the camera, make sure to call controls.update() so the OrbitControls gets a chance to enforce its constraints on the camera.

`Stack Overflow is getting really stupid about posting requirements`

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed